# Angular.js Model Traversal

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a function that goes like $.each(scope.model)? A function that traverses all the models within a scope?

I can't seem to find an answer anywhere and thought maybe I should give SO a try.

Thanks!

-Jan

---

EDIT:

So I've been playing around the code and found a workaround on this.

Fiddle [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/CBSaj/3/)

```
function ResetScope(scope){
    $(scope).each(function () {
        if(!(this instanceof Function)){           
            for (var key in this) {
                if(key.indexOf("$") !== -1 || key.indexOf("this") !== -1)
                    continue;
                else
                    if(key instanceof Function){
                        continue;
                    }else if(this[key].indexOf("function") !== -1){                        
                        continue;
                    }else{
                        alert(this[key]);
                        this[key] = "";
                        console.log(this);
                    }
            }
        }
    });  
    return scope;
}
```

The only thing that is not so awesome is that when you have a variable with a "function" in its name, it might also be filtered out. Well, at least for now, this snippet works. For those who have their answers, feel free to post your answer. Might be helpful to others.

Comment: does it need to be recursive?

Comment: It can be. But it's not really a requirement. My use for this is to reset all the scope's model value to default, perhaps an empty string, or to an undefined state.

Comment: angular.forEach(variable,function(value,key){});

Comment: Why not just use the angular.forEach or native javascript for in statement? angular.forEach( $scope, function( val,key ){}), or for(obj in $scope){...}

Comment: I'm trying out jQuery's .each() now, fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/CBSaj/
And as you might notice when you run it, the $scope.reset() function would still be included in the filter. Any thoughts? I can't get if(key instanceOf Function) to check whether or not $scope.reset() is really a function.

Comment: just try native in or ECMA 5 Object.Keys

Comment: Something which should be noted: Your "model" values your using should be put into one object like $scope.model = {'name': 'foo', 'initial': bar'}. If you don't do this scope inheritance may later not work as you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference, Brian's Batarang tool has this code in [appInspect.js](https://github.com/angular/angularjs-batarang/blob/master/js/services/appInspect.js):

```
var thisScope = angular.element(this).scope();
var models = {};
for (prop in thisScope) {
    if (thisScope.hasOwnProperty(prop) && prop !== 'this' && prop[0] !== '$') {
        models[prop] = thisScope[prop];
    }
}
var str = JSON.stringify(models);
```

Comment: Batarang! Why haven't I thought of that? Thanks Mark!